# ORA-00001 in UPDATE statement without duplicate

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I fail to understand the logic of the unique constraint when it's based on 2 fields.

I have the following table named `DESCRIPTIONS` including 3 columns: `ID_DESCRIPTION`, `NAME`, `ID_DESCRIPTION_TYPE`

Now `ID_DESCRIPTION` is the `primary key`, and there is a `unique constraint` `UK_DESCRIPTION` on couple (`ID_DESCRIPTION`, `NAME`).

If I try to run the following query:

```
UPDATE DESCRIPTIONS SET NAME = 'USA' WHERE ID_DESCRIPTION = 9255813
```

I'm getting an `ORA-00001` exception, saying that unique constraint `UK_DESCRIPTION` is violated.

Now this would mean that the couple (`9255813`,`'USA'`) already exists right ?
However, I don't see how this is possible since the `ID_DESCRIPTION` is a `primary key` and therefore unique AND the results of the query

```
SELECT * FROM  DESCRIPTIONS  WHERE ID_DESCRIPTION = 9255813
```

only return 1 result, the one I want to update.
What am I failing to understand here ?

[image: Constraint snapshot from toad]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement including all constraints and indexes to your table. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that `uk_description` is in fact a unique key based on the single column of NAME.

> "It is unfortunately not."

Okay, the other explanation is that it is a multi-column key based on a different set of columns from what you think. `(NAME, ID_DESCRIPTION_TYPE)` would also fit the described behaviour.

To be fair, a unique key on`(NAME, ID_DESCRIPTION_TYPE)` makes more sense. For example, this is the key you'd want when the table is a single reference data look-up (which is a horrible model but common enough). Whereas a compound key of `ID_DESCRIPTION, NAME)` would do nothing but undermine the primary key.

Comment: It is unfortunately not.

Comment: You were actually not that far away, I did not read the constraint correctly, is based on (ID_DESCRIPTION_TYPE, NAME) and not (ID_DESCRIPTION, NAME)

Comment: As it happens I was typing that up as a second guess :-)